# malloc , how free return value in a function

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, return, free

My app is use in stlinux (sh4) and unfortunately valgrind does not support sh4 cpu.
since I saw memory leak with my app, I had used mtrace, and it confirmed that some memory is not free. The problem is, variable of malloc used in the return, therefore I do not have any idea, how could I free it (since if it would be free, then returning in the functions is meaningless)?

I had written cs_malloc (put bellow code from oscam-simple.c in above link), mtrace log says, that in line:

```
*tmp = malloc (size);
```

memory is not free

```
 /* This function encapsulates malloc. It automatically adds an error message to the log if it failed and calls cs_exit(quiterror) if quiterror > -1. 
       result will be automatically filled with the new memory position or NULL on failure. */
    void *cs_malloc(void *result, size_t size, int32_t quiterror){
        void **tmp = result;
        *tmp = malloc (size);
        if(*tmp == NULL){
            cs_log("Couldn't allocate memory (errno=%d %s)!", errno, strerror(errno));
            if(quiterror > -1) cs_exit(quiterror);
        } else {
            memset(*tmp, 0, size);  
        }
        return *tmp;
    }
```

And then for malloc, I call it, like this:

```
  // create the AES key entry for the linked list
    if(!cs_malloc(&new_entry, sizeof(AES_ENTRY), -1)) return;
```

Please take a look at these 3 functions (which malloc is not free , and as other users said, valgrind claim that these codes cause memory leaks [module-datastruct-llist.c](http://www.streamboard.tv/oscam/browser/trunk/module-datastruct-llist.c?rev=5375)

The memory leaks cause by 3 different parts:

1. in below codes "new" would never free , but since it use in return of that function, I don't have idea, how could I free it:

   ```
   LL_NODE* ll_append_nolock(LLIST *l, void *obj)
   {
   if (l && obj) {
       LL_NODE *new;
       if(!cs_malloc(&new,sizeof(LL_NODE), -1)) return NULL;
       new->obj = obj;

       if (l->last)
           l->last->nxt = new;
       else
           l->initial = new;
       l->last = new;    

       l->count++;
       return new;
       }  
       }
   ```
2. also "l" use in below function, again since it use in return function, I have no idea how to free it. :

   ```
     LLIST *ll_create()
     {
      LLIST *l = cs_malloc(&l, sizeof(LLIST), 0);
      pthread_mutex_init(&l->lock, NULL);
      return l;
      }
   ```
3. same story with new :

   ```
            LL_NODE *ll_prepend(LLIST *l, void *obj)
           {             
           if (l && obj) {

           LL_NODE *new;
           if(!cs_malloc(&new,sizeof(LL_NODE), -1)) return NULL;

           new->obj = obj;
           ll_lock(l);
           new->nxt = l->initial;

           l->initial = new;
           if (!l->last)
               l->last = l->initial;
           l->count++;
           ll_unlock(l);

           return new;
       }
          return NULL;
       }
   ```

For more functions you could see [module-datastruct-llist.c](http://www.streamboard.tv/oscam/browser/trunk/module-datastruct-llist.c?rev=5375)

Would highly appreciate, if any expert tell me, how could I fix that memory leak (if you feel, cs_malloc should be rewritten, or need to add new function, please write the source code you are meaning.

Comment: For take a deeper look deeper in entire source code , please check this trac browser] :
http://www.streamboard.tv/oscam/browser/trunk/?rev=5375

Comment: Did you consider compiling and testing your application on a standard x86 or x86_64 Linux distribution and use `valgrind` on it?

Comment: Other than my C compiler whining about an invalid implicit assignment from void* to void** (but I know what it is trying to do, so a cast clears that) the cs_malloc() function appears sound (or i've not had enough coffee this morning), so I don't think your problem lies there. Start checking the usage.

Answer (score 0):

The most common implementations of malloc use heap memory, which is global, so it's very common to have storage allocated in one place passed around between a number of functions before it is finally freed.

Now, there are for instance calls to ll_append_nolock where you ignore the malloced return. I.e.

```
ll_append_nolock(it->l, obj);
```

so to avoid a leak you need to do what you do in other places, i.e let the calling function receive the allocated memory into a pointer:

```
LL_NODE *n = ll_append_nolock(l, obj);
/* do stuff with "n", which points to memory allocated under the name of "new" */
free(n);
```

And when you're through with n (which as noted above points to the storage allocted under the name "new", that is: same memory, different names), you free it.

HTH.

Comment: If the name (ll_append_nolock) lives up to its name, the allocated node returned via that pointer is also attached to the linked list (l). If not, I concur, and freeing it is mandated, otherwise won't this result in an invalid node in the linked list?

Answer (score 0):

In your function `cs_malloc` the first parameter is `result` however you never assign to it in the function `cs_malloc`.

Later you use `cs_malloc` like this

```
if(!cs_malloc(&new,sizeof(LL_NODE), -1)) return NULL;
    new->obj = obj;
```

which will not work since since "new" is left uninitialized

you should either assign to result in your `cs_malloc` or just return the block in `cs_malloc`, if you fail to allocate just return `NULL` instead.

e.g.

```
void *cs_malloc(size_t size, int32_t quiterror)
{
  void* tmp = calloc(1,size);
  if(tmp == NULL)
  {
    cs_log("Couldn't allocate memory (errno=%d %s)!", errno, strerror(errno));
    if(quiterror > -1) cs_exit(quiterror);
  } 
  return tmp;
}
```

and

```
  if (new = cs_malloc(sizeof(LL_NODE),-1))
  {
    new->obj = obj;
  }
  else
  {
    return NULL;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anders
Thanks for reply , i would take consideration your note  ,an would change it as u described to see memory leaks how it's goes...

**How , this line should be change to the new cs_malloc function u had written:**
1.

```
    LLIST *l = cs_malloc(&l, sizeof(LLIST), 0);
    pthread_mutex_init(&l->lock, NULL);
    return l;
```

2.

```
if(!cs_malloc(&para,sizeof(struct read_thread_param), -1)) return FALSE;
            para->id=i;
```